# PrimeNg Table toggle cell editing

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am using primeng table and want to make a column editable on a button click. However I am unable to do this. I don't know which property I have to set in order to toggle editing. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my template:

```html
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-state let-expanded="expanded" let-columns="columns" >
        <tr>
            <td pEditableColumn>
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.id">
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData.id}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First option** which I feel better to achieve this is, by disabling input controls as mentioned below.

```
<input [disabled]="!editable" pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.id">
```

you can make the editable property to true or false on button click.  The control will be visible on cell click still it is ok as it is not editable.

**Second option** is to duplicating the cell with editable condition as mentioned below.

```
<td pEditableColumn *ngIf="editable" >
            <p-cellEditor>
                <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                    <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.id">
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                    {{rowData.id}}
                </ng-template>
            </p-cellEditor>
 </td>

<td *ngIf="!editable">{{rowData.id}}</td>
```